# Synonym [framework7] and [html-framework-7]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[framework7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework7) and [html-framework-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-framework-7)

Both reference the same [Framework7](http://framework7.io/) project and there is [significant overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bframework7%5D%5Bhtml-framework-7%5D&mixed=0). I would say [html-framework-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-framework-7) is the tag that needs to remain.

Comment: All true. There could be other Framework 7, like entity, it's sooner or later going to reach that number. `html-framework-7` is the right name.

Comment: frameworkio seems a good compromise to make sure no other framework# namespace collide.

Comment: @Braiam I think that would be confusing to users, tho

Comment: Well, obviously, I forgot to type the number...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agree, but [framework7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework7) needs to be the main tag. ["Framework7" is the official name of the project](http://framework7.io/docs/) -- no space and no mention of "html". And it's not a common word or something, so there will be no confusion regarding what it refers to.

Comment: Not an exact match, but not a unique naming pattern either.  eg, Cold Fusion has [Framework 1](http://framework-one.github.io/documentation/).  Just appending html to framework-7 wouldn't really be that large of a help though since CF is also a web framework.